# how to handle images from API in a swiper

Tags: javascript, image, rest, api, react-native

I installed `react-native-swiper` and I swipe 3 full screen views and everything is okay, but I have to swipe images from an API, I'll receive images from an API. I dont know how to display it, because the number of images will change everytime I can't put my images in my project
I have to utilize flatList in one view or what ?

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

        <Swiper autoplay={true} loop={true} style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={true}>
            <View style={styles.slide1}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Dima Arcol 1</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.slide2}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Dima Arcol 2</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.slide3}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Dima Arcol 3</Text>
            </View>
        </Swiper>
        <View style={styles.myButtunContainer}>
            <MyLButton/>
        </View>

    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your data using map.
lets say your data is

```
data = [
    {
        text: 'imageheading',
        image: 'yoururl'
    },
    ...
];

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

    <Swiper autoplay={true} loop={true} style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={true}>

    {this.data.map((data) => {
        return(
            <View style={styles.slide3}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{data.text}</Text>
                <Image src={{ uri: data.image }}/>
            </View>
        );
    })}
    </Swiper>
    <View style={styles.myButtunContainer}>
        <MyLButton/>
    </View>

    </View>
);
```

Comment: I edited at the same time when you did it., thats why

Comment: Is your data inside redux?

Comment: It should be pretty simple, just use your data as this.props.data, and so on. Using redux won't change this.

Comment: no, I want use redux for this also, it's possible ? or maybe I have to use it just like this and use redux for other things ?